# Error message while running AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

In my flex code I cann't find any error...But while running the application the problem window shows following error.

> Description Resource Path Location
>   Type  Can not resolve a multiname
>   reference unambiguously.
>   mx.rpc.http.mxml:HTTPService (from
>   C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash
>   Builder
>   4\sdks\4.1.0\frameworks\libs\rpc.swc(mx.rpc.http.mxml:HTTPService))
>   and mx.rpc.http:HTTPService (from
>   C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash
>   Builder
>   4\sdks\4.1.0\frameworks\libs\rpc.swc(mx.rpc.http:HTTPService))
>   are
>   available.    VL1.mxml    /VL1/src    Unknown Flex
>   Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Can not resolve a multiname reference
>   unambiguously.
>   mx.rpc.http.mxml:HTTPService (from
>   C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash
>   Builder
>   4\sdks\4.1.0\frameworks\libs\rpc.swc(mx.rpc.http.mxml:HTTPService))
>   and mx.rpc.http:HTTPService (from
>   C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash
>   Builder
>   4\sdks\4.1.0\frameworks\libs\rpc.swc(mx.rpc.http:HTTPService))
>   are
>   available.    VL1.mxml    /VL1/src    Unknown Flex
>   Problem

Anyone please help me to

> solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are including two different classes that have the same name and are conflicting.

You have:

```
mx.rpc.http.mxml:HTTPService
```

And

```
mx.rpc.http:HTTPService
```

Make sure that in this two are not being included in your code.